# Fantasy Book, maybe series, guy wakes up with power of a god, out for revenge

Tags: story-identification

A contemporary fantasy novel, published after 2000, probably American. I started reading it a couple of years ago but I never finished. If I remember correctly, the gods were either dead, or basically just like kings. Humans could inherit their power through a task or something, but having the power of a god would kill you quickly. I think at the beginning the guy may have just died and was resurrected. I think he's either inherited the power of Bacchus, is out to kill Bacchus, or both.

Comment: Is it Dominion by Bentley Little? https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/108571.Dominion

Comment: Is it any of Rick Riordan's Percy Jackson books/series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_Jackson_%26_the_Olympians

Comment: @AlexM it does sound like Dionysus. I have the book and it matches in some respects though not all. Are you going to post that as an answer?

Comment: Same god I think, but the book was not YA

Comment: @JohnRennie I am not; I haven't read any of those books, just hoping to jog the OP's memory with some quick guesses.